# Unity special scripts name

Tags: unity-game-engine, filenames, assets

This is something interesting I have noticed recently and couldn't find it anywhere in Unity documentations.

There are specific names that if I assign them to a script, it gets a different icon from the usual script icon (tested it on c# scripts only).

For example:

**GameManager** gets a gear icon.

**Folder** gets a folder icon

**Favorite** gets a star icon

**Search** get magnification glass icon

**All icons are scrips:**
[image: All icons are scripts]

My computer runs Windows 7 and my Unity version is 2017.3.1f1 (64 bit).

Does anyone else have noticed it and knows why is that, and are there any more special names?

Comment: There are about ~200 special script names. I now believe that this is just a coincidence and not "special". I discovered a pattern about this few weeks ago. Some Textures that comes with Unity, when the name match with some of those textures, it will inherit the icon that comes with Unity and this is why it's not documented. The list is too much to be listed

Comment: So maybe this is a bug in Unity's assets viewer. I find it quite interesting because now every time I create a script I don't know if it is a special name

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug. Since you're curios, I just modified my other answer and added some details on how to find them. I also added my Editor script to do that there. It can find most of them.